# Sending a subview of a collection view cell to the back stops it from changing backgroundColor

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, background-color, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and I'm adding a subview to its `contentView` so that its delete button look like it's hovering over the corner of the cell but a little bit outside the bounds (Just like the delete button of an app in springboard). All works fine but when I try to change this subview `insetView.backgroundColor` after the cell is highlighted or selected it doesn't change.

In **UICollectionViewCell**

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.insetView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, self.bounds.size.width/64, self.bounds.size.height/16)];
    self.insetView.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    self.insetView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.insetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:65/255.0 green:166/255.0 blue:42/255.0 alpha:1];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.insetView];
    [self.contentView sendSubviewToBack:self.insetView];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

In **CollectionViewController**

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JamCollectionViewCell *cell = (JamCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView *v = [[cell.contentView subviews] firstObject];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

I also tried

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  JamCollectionViewCell *cell = (JamCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];   
  cell.insetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
}
```

And tried all combinations i. e. trying to get the subview by its order and change its background color in the `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath` and trying to get the subview by its property name `cell.insetView` and change its background color in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` but nothing worked.

Funny thing is that if the subview `cell.insetView` is **NOT** sent to the back of the `cell.contentView` it **does** respond to changing the background color both ways and anywhere. Hence the question title.

Sorry for the long question and thanks for your help.

Comment: If you set the view to blue before sending it to the back, can you still see it?

Comment: Yup. I did `self.insetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];` just before `[self.contentView sendSubviewToBack:self.insetView];` in UICollectionViewCell and it's blue now instead of green (the original color).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell` have built in state management for `select` and `highlight`, but have no visible response to it.  You might try moving this logic into your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, you might find you have better luck.

If you're loading your code from a NIB or Storyboard you can override `awakeFromNib` to create your custom background view (or add it in the storyboard and connect it to the cell via an `IBOutlet`).  Otherwise add it wherever you are creating your other views.

Then you can override `setSelected:` and `setHighlighted:` (remember to call super) in your custom subclass to adjust the colors based on the current state.  I have done this a number of times as an implementation for a selection state, and it continues to work in iOS 9.

Code that worked for the poster:

```
(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    if (selected) {
        self.insetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    else {
        self.insetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:65/255.0 green:166/255.0 blue:42/255.0 alpha:1];
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks. Please add the code to your answer for other users. `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    
    if (selected) {
        self.insetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    } else {
        self.insetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:65/255.0 green:166/255.0 blue:42/255.0 alpha:1];
    }
}`

Comment: For the record I typically extract that code into a private method and call it from the `setSelected:` and `setHighlighted:` implementation, then I check `if (selected || highlighted)` instead of just `if (selected)`.